# Is there a way to use MinGW without changing Path variable?

Tags: python, c, windows

So I recently started learning C, and right after i installed the gcc compiler, I realized that the path had to be set to the compiler for me to use it through the cmd prompt.The problem with that is I am doing python as well as C at the same time, and both of them require the Path variable to be set to something specific. So I guess i could change the Path every time I run a specific language, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can permanently  add additional paths to your PATH env variable. At cmd prompt issue the following command   `setx path "%path%;x:\path\to\python;\path\to\gcc"`

Comment: Try @YuriGinsburg proposal (Yuri, consider making that an answer please). I am surprised that you are not aware of the possibility to have more than one path in that variable or that the value you are currently using does not already have more than one. Otherwise if you really want to use mingw without appropriate path variable, which I doubt, then you can always use  the full absolute path `x:\path\to\gccdir\gcc` in your commandlines, instead if only `gcc`. I doubt that you are asking for that, because that annoyance was the reason for introducing the path variable, so please clarify.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I think in the context of what OP describes and wants the word "permantly" is not really to the point in your comment. As far as I understand, your command would temporarily, i.e. for the time of using the same shell/prompt, addit, but NOT permanently. Which only makes your proposal better actually, but the phrasing seems a little off.

Comment: @Yunnosch You are absolutely right. I am not a Windows person, and  I should stress on adding multiple paths.
Malhar needs help with pathman command.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way add *both* passes to path variable is to run setx command.

```
setx path "%path%;x:\path\to\python;\path\to\gcc"
```

This will take effect only for console session (Thx @Yunnosch for pointing this).
To make the new path really permanent consider downloading and running `pathhman.exe`
See https://www.windows-commandline.com/set-path-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

I never set the PATH for an individual language.

I use MinGW-w64 GCC either from an IDE like Code::Blocks (see http://winlibs.com/ for instructions to add seperate win32 and win64 GCC to Code::Blocks), or from MSYS2, where I have a `.profile` script in my home folder setting environment variables like PATH. This way I even have different MSYS2/MinGW combinations on the same system.